# How to catch exceptions within BlockCode (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Is there a proper way to catch exceptions within block code?

I got the following code:

```
void(^callback(int) = ^(int respond){
   [self DoSomethingWithRespond:respond]; //this throws an exception
};

-(void)DoSomethingWithRespond:(int)respond{
   if(respond == 400){
     NSException *exception = [NSException 
                              exceptionWithName:@"Failed" 
                              reason:logMessage 
                              userInfo:nil];
     @throw exception
   }
}
```

The callback methods gets called from another thread. If the respond is equal to 400 the `DoSomethingWithRespond` method will throw an exception.

Comment: In Objective-c Exceptions are used only for exceptional, i.e. unforeseeable circumstances, i.e. programmer errors

Comment: But i want to catch that exception, programmer error or not.. :-)

Comment: sure, i know it's not an answer. I upvoted so hopefully you will get one. As long as you are aware that what you are doing is considered absolutely awful code, i wish you luck.

Comment: Thanks for the up vote, i know its dirty code but I'm only explaining the concept for my code, this isn't actually the code itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    @try {
        <#statements#>
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        <#handler#>
    }
    @finally {
        <#statements#>
    }
```

Comment: O my god.. Seems like it just doesn't autocomplete within a block code. But the `@try - catch` seems to work... Thank you!